# kustomize, secretGenerator & patchesStrategicMerge: envFrom.secretRef not reading hashed secret name

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

In my `kustomization.yaml` I have:

```yaml
...
secretGenerator:
  - name: db-env
    behavior: create
    envs:
      - my.env
patchesStrategicMerge:
  - app.yaml
```

And then in my `app.yaml` (the patch) I have:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app-deployment
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: server
          envFrom:
            - secretRef:
                name: db-env
```

When I try build this via `kustomize build k8s/development` I get back out:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
...
    spec:
      containers:
      - envFrom:
        - secretRef:
            name: db-env
        name: server
```

When it should be:

```yaml
      - envFrom:
        - secretRef:
            name: db-env-4g95hhmhfc
```

How do I get the `secretGenerator` name hashing to apply to `patchesStrategicMerge` too?

Or alternatively, what's the proper way to inject some environment vars into a deployment for a specific overlay?

This for development.

---

My file structure is like:

```
❯ tree k8s
k8s
├── base
│   ├── app.yaml
│   └── kustomization.yaml
├── development
│   ├── app.yaml
│   ├── golinks.sql
│   ├── kustomization.yaml
│   ├── mariadb.yaml
│   ├── my.cnf
│   └── my.env
└── production
    ├── ingress.yaml
    └── kustomization.yaml
```

Where `base/kustomization.yaml` is:

```yaml
namespace: go-mpen
resources:
- app.yaml
images:
- name: server
  newName: reg/proj/server
```

and `development/kustomization.yaml` is:

```yaml
resources:
  - ../base
  - mariadb.yaml
configMapGenerator:
  - name: mariadb-config
    files:
      - my.cnf
  - name: initdb-config
    files:
      - golinks.sql  # TODO: can we mount this w/out a config file?
secretGenerator:
  - name: db-env
    behavior: create
    envs:
      - my.env
patchesStrategicMerge:
  - app.yaml
```

Comment: Found a github issue about this: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/issues/1553

Answer (score 3):

This works fine for me with `kustomize v3.8.4`.  Can you please check your version and if `disableNameSuffixHash` is not perhaps set to you true.

Here are the manifests used by me to test this:

```
➜  app.yaml  deployment.yaml  kustomization.yaml   my.env
```

app.yaml

```
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app-deployment
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: server
          envFrom:
            - secretRef:
                name: db-env
```

deplyoment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app-deployment 
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.14.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

and my kustomization.yaml

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

secretGenerator:
  - name: db-env
    behavior: create
    envs:
      - my.env
patchesStrategicMerge:
  - app.yaml

resources: 
  - deployment.yaml
```

And here is the result:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  ASD: MTIz
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: db-env-f5tt4gtd7d
type: Opaque
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: nginx
  name: app-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx:1.14.2
        name: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
      - envFrom:
        - secretRef:
            name: db-env-f5tt4gtd7d
        name: server
```

Comment: I have kustomize `v3.8.1`... just tried upgrading, no dice. I think the difference between yours and mine is that I have two `kustomization.yaml`s... one for the base and one for the overlay. I've noticed other things don't seem to apply recursively either, even though I think they should.

Comment: Why is it necessary to have to apply a patch to get this to work?? Having the envFrom directly in deployment.yaml should have worked, but it doesn't.